# Confusing CORS errors and how to use a CORS proxy

Tags: javascript, cors

So I've been working on an in browser program that uses fetch to get some data from an api, and because the api only returns data in chunks I need to send a total of 70-100 requests, one after another at about 5/second. However about 50% of the time I get a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?page=49&key=7a5825e3-2d47-4ff4-894f-7fd2a6c9ca17' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Strangely enough, when it does happen, the error seems to occur at a random point through the 80 or so requests. I understand the concept of a CORS proxy but I cannot figure out how to use it in practice. Could someone explain how to use any of the CORS proxy websites to avoid this error.

Comment: Are you using axios?

Comment: No I am not, just pure js

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use `axios` since fetch is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: This software isn't designed to be public, otherwise I would. Its just a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your package.json:

```
"proxy": {
      "*":{ "target" : "http://myurl"}
   }
```

And set headers like:

```
 axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/json;charset=utf-8';
  axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
```

Comment: Sorry that I did not make this clear but I do not have backend access to this API, this is a public one and I am just using it.

Comment: @BenjaminKantor this is for the client configuration. Maybe he thought you're using React, Angular, etc.